# C# Json LinQ - Build Json String Using Loop

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to produce a Json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "fromAddress": {
    "streetLines": [
      "100 Test St",
      "Ste 100"
    ],
    "city": "Orlando",
    "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
    "postalCode": "32819",
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  "toAddress": {
    "streetLines": [
      "101 Test St",
      null
    ],
    "city": "Orlando",
    "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
    "postalCode": "32819",
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  "packageDimensions": [
   {
      "weight": 20.0,
      "length": "18",
      "width": "12",
      "height": "13"
   },
   {
      "weight": 20.0,
      "length": "18",
      "width": "12",
      "height": "13"
   },
   {
      "weight": 20.0,
      "length": "18",
      "width": "12",
      "height": "13"
   }
   ]
}
```

I've gotten this far with my code:

```
        var json = new
            {
                fromAddress = new
                {
                    streetLines = new[]
                    {
                        fromAddress1,
                        fromAddress2
                    },
                    city = fromCity,
                    stateOrProvinceCode = fromState,
                    postalCode = fromZip,
                    countryCode = fromCountry
                },
                toAddress = new
                {
                    streetLines = new[]
                    {
                        toAddress1,
                        toAddress2
                    },
                    city = toCity,
                    stateOrProvinceCode = toState,
                    postalCode = toZip,
                    countryCode = toCountry
                },
            };
```

That produces the following, which is lacking the pack dimensions:

```
{
  "fromAddress": {
    "streetLines": [
      "100 Test St",
      "Ste 100"
    ],
    "city": "Orlando",
    "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
    "postalCode": "32819",
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  "toAddress": {
    "streetLines": [
      "101 Test St",
      null
    ],
    "city": "Orlando",
    "stateOrProvinceCode": "FL",
    "postalCode": "32819",
    "countryCode": "US"
  }
}
```

My data for the pack dimensions are stored thusly:

```
List<double> weight
string length
string width
string height
```

Multiple values for weight are passed in with the List, the dimensions are constants.

I need to find a way to add the pack dimensions, iterating through the weight List to do so. But I'm not sure how to approach it, adding a loop in the Json build doesn't work in any way.

I would appreciate any advice on getting the data iteration that I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add LINQ expression with projection:

```cs
var json = new
    {
        fromAddress = new
        {
            streetLines = new[]
            {
                fromAddress1,
                fromAddress2
            },
            city = fromCity,
            stateOrProvinceCode = fromState,
            postalCode = fromZip,
            countryCode = fromCountry
        },
        toAddress = new
        {
            streetLines = new[]
            {
                toAddress1,
                toAddress2
            },
            city = toCity,
            stateOrProvinceCode = toState,
            postalCode = toZip,
            countryCode = toCountry
        },
        packageDimensions = weight.Select(w => new 
        {
            weight = w,
            length = length,
            width = width,
            height = height
        })
        .ToArray()
    };
```